# In JavaScript, how can I store an array of object value into string variable?

Tags: javascript

I have this object with the following data that I need to store in a variable:

```
user: [
  {
    firstname: 'John',
    lastname: 'Doe',
    roles: [
      {
        roleId: 18,
        displayText: 'accountant',
        description: 'accountant'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am looping through this object as such:

```
let selectedRole = user.roles.map((role, index) => {
  return role.displayText
})
```

*selectedRole* returns me the following output: ["accountant"]

**For example:**
John Doe has only 1 role assigned to him -> account
Sam Williams has 3 roles assigned -> program manager, account, admin

let's say if I click on Sam William's details then I want to see all the roles that I assigned to him in not comma separated but in the following layout:

Role 1: program manager

Role 2: account

Role 3: admin

Comment: map returns an array. If you have more roles, the array will contain more values. If you want to access the first item, you just call arr[0].

Comment: `user.roles[0].displayText`

Comment: @Trace let's assume if I have more roles, then how would I display those without the brackets?

Comment: @user10248088 Well not, because it would be an array... in what format would you want to receive multiple values otherwise? To concatenate string or stuff like that you would reduce.

Comment: Your question is confusing... Take your variable naming; `selectedRole` suggests you want to target a single role, but your comments conflict with that intent. Should that be `selectedRoles`? Should your output be `"accountant, other, another"` if there are multiple? Try to clarify your issue.

Comment: Arrays are a fundamental and basic part of javascript.  If you do not recognise that square brackets are an array, then you are most likely attempting to do something way above your ability level.

Comment: json dot stringify and parse after

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to get all elements of the array as a delimited string, you can use `Array.prototype.join`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

```js
let selectedRoles = user.roles.map((role, index) => {
  return role.displayText
});

let rolesString = selectedRoles.join();
```

If `selectedRoles` is `['accountant', 'admin']` then the value of `rolesString` will be `accountant, admin`. The parameter of `join` is optional, but its value is the delimiter (comma is default).

**EDIT**

So if you don't want them as one string, but instead you want to display them individually on the screen. How are you displaying them? Are you using Angular or some other library/framework, or are you using plain JavaScript?

If you're using Angular, for example, you'll use its mechanisms for looping over a collection. So:

```html
<ul *ngFor="let role of selectedRoles; let idx = index">
    <li>Role {{idx}}: {{role}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I added the `index` functionality as well, in case that's desired. Also, why was my answer downvoted?

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need an array, but just the string, then don't use `.map`:

```js
const user = [
  {
    firstname: 'John',
    lastname: 'Doe',
    roles: [
      {
        roleId: 18,
        displayText: 'accountant',
        description: 'accountant'
      }
    ]
  }
];

const selectedRole = user[0].roles[0].displayText;
console.log(selectedRole);
```

If you want to join all roles into a string, use `.join` by whatever delimiter you want:

```js
const user = [
  {
    firstname: 'John',
    lastname: 'Doe',
    roles: [
      {
        roleId: 18,
        displayText: 'accountant',
        description: 'accountant'
      },
      {
        roleId: 20,
        displayText: 'somethingElse',
        description: 'somethingElse'
      }
    ]
  }
];

const selectedRole = user[0].roles.map((r, i) => `Role ${i + 1}: ${r.displayText}`).join('\n');
console.log(selectedRole);
```

Comment: if I have more roles, then it won't be 0 index anymore. How would I display the rest of the roles then?

Comment: How would you want to "display the rest of the roles" without an array? You said you wanted a string.

Comment: I just updated my post. Please see the recent update.

Comment: Then you do need to use `.map`, and return a string inside the callback, then `.join`

Comment: If your desired output is as you've said in your question, `Role 1: program manager
Role 2: account
Role 3: admin`, I'm pretty sure my answer produces that much better than the answer you've accepted, nor does my answer deserve a downvote, can you double-check?